# Displaying a word document in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, ms-word, jpanel, apache-poi

I have a word document with images in it in my hard drive. Is it possible to display this word document in JPanel using Java?

Comment: This might not be true, but there's a high chance that such an operation is much easier in .NET/C#, since they're both Microsoft technologies. If your purpose is not very attached to Java, I highly recommend you look into this.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't display a Word document in a JPanel.

But you can use the `Desktop` class. See [How to Integrate With the Desktop Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html).

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to get the text using a library like Apache POI (although HWPF is currently not managed). But retrieving the images may be substantially more complex.